# Нужно чтобы чат бот удалял сообщение в чате на которое я отвечу конкретным словом

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Например, человек в чате написал что либо, я ответил на его сообщение и после этого мой бот должен удалить сообщение на которое я ответил.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать команду, которая доступна только администраторам чата. Примерно так:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=["delete"])
def delete_message(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    
    if message.type not in ("group", "supergroup"):
        # Команда используется не в чате
        return None

    chat_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, message.from_user.id)
    if not member.can_delete_messages:
        # У пользователя нет прав удалять сообщения
        return None

    if message.reply_to_message is None:
        # Команда используется не ответом на сообщение
        return bot.reply_to(message, "Эту команду нужно использовать ответом на сообщение...")

    bot.delete_message(chat_id, message.reply_to_message.message_id)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @Ariel если ответ помог, то отметить его как правильный было бы неплохо :)